# How to set dynamic value in jQuery css() function with !important declaration?

Tags: jquery, css

In the following jQuery script, I am trying to replace "2500px" with $(document).height() but it's not working.

```
$("#mydiv").css("cssText", "position: relative; width:30%; height:2500px!important;");
```

This is what I did but it's not working:

```
$("#mydiv").css("cssText", "position: relative; width:30%; height:"+$(document).height()+"!important;");
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/css/ and http://api.jquery.com/attr/. You can use `$( "#div" ).attr( "style", "height: " + $(document).height() + "px !important;" )`

Answer (score -1):

**Updated:**
You can use cssText like below:

```
$('#mydiv').css('cssText','height: 2500px !important');
```

Comment: As per my understanding You don't need important with inline-styling

Comment: He wants to replace the `2500px` width the document height, shouldn't your code be `$("#mydiv").css('height',$(document).height()+'px','important');`

Comment: Yes `.css()` addes inline style to element like `<div style='....'>` just to add not downvoter

Comment: There is no 3rd parameter for jQuery's [.css](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: @Satpal No, it doesn't

Comment: @C-linkNepal Yes it does.